# TypeError: this.props.dishes is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm with trouble using props on React.
See my code:

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
import './App.css';
import { DISHES } from './shared/dishes';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu disches={this.state.disches}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my MenuContent code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Media } from 'reactstrap';

class Menu extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render(){
        
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) =>{
            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
                    <Media tag="li">
                        <Media left middle>
                            <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
                        </Media>
                        <Media body className="ml-5">
                            <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
                            <p>{dish.description}</p>
                        </Media>
                    </Media>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <Media list>
                        {menu}
                    </Media>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

And finally here the error:

```
TypeError: this.props.dishes is undefined

  11 | 
  12 |    render(){
  13 |        
> 14 |        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) =>{
  15 |            return (
  16 |                <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
                   <Media tag="li">
```

Before this I have used a local data and used this.state.dish and it works fine, but now I'm trying to get the data from another file and when I change the state for props, this error stuck me
Can somebody help please?

Comment: You have a typo `<Menu disches={this.state.disches}` instead of `dishes`

Comment: It's also better to add empty exception handling like `this.props?.dishes.map`

Comment: @LolWalid that's the point, i need to pay more attention. Thank you very much!